# JDO MakePersistent overwrite previous entry

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I am using JDO to store objects in GAE for a GWT project. I have a problem with the creation of new objects. It works great the first time I create an object. However the second time, it overwrites the previous one with another Key value which I find very strange. I should say that I can create a new object if a refresh the page. This is the code I'm using. The post parameter is a new object and I think that the new ID on the datastore entity proves this. What I don't understand is where my previously created object went.

```
public static Post addPost(Post post) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try{
        tx.begin();
        post.getTopic().addPost(post);
        pm.makePersistent(post.getTopic());
        pm.detachCopyAll(post.getTopic());
        tx.commit();

    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive())
            tx.rollback();
        pm.close();
    }
    return post;
}
```

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, you need to lookup the currently persisted `Topic`, update it with new values then persist it again. As DN said in his answer, persisting a `Transient` (i.e. I'm not sure what that is but let's say it's a newly created java object), will simply persist a new object. I guess the overriding mechanism is applied by the data-store, not DN (i.e. due to a unique key violation). May I ask why are you detaching the list if you are not returning it ? I'm still learning so I'm not disapproving your code or anything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer! It helped me in thinking it some other ways and helped me solve the problem. I don't really have any explanation for detaching it. It was just some desperate "maybe this will help" thing I added. Removed that line later since it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem now and it didn't had anything to do with the data store really. The problem was that the topic I had was passed from the client.  This topic was updated on page load and thereafter never updated. Therefore I was always passing the old topic to the function which didn't have the newly added posts in it. Therefore it would "overwrite" the previous element in the topics post list. I solved this by looking up the topic at the server side before adding the new post to it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you may attention to [object lifecycle state](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/object_lifecycle.html). Passing a transient object into persist will persist it, as per the publically available JDO spec. Your `Post` class is not shown, nor the values it has at entry or what was in the datastore, nor the log (which tells you what PUT is made)

Comment: I'm still trying to grasp the object life cycle with JDO so here is my question, which is related to the original question. To update a currently persisted object, I should look it up, NOT detach it, close the `PersistenceManager`, update the object outside of the lookup method, then open a whole new `PersistenceManager` and persist the object with it's updated values ? Would that work fine to update existing objects ?